# Determine all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\cosh{\frac1{n}}-\cos{\frac1{n}})^{\alpha}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left ( \cosh{\frac1{n}}-\cos{\frac1{n}}\right )^{\alpha}$$

I tried using D'Alembert's criterium

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\left ( \cosh{\frac1{n+1}}-\cos{\frac1{n+1}}\right )^{\alpha}}{\left ( \cosh{\frac1{n}}-\cos{\frac1{n}}\right )^{\alpha}}$$ but I am not getting anywhere. Can someone give me hint or idea?

Comment: Look at the Taylor series of $\cosh$ and $\cos$. Think a bit about how many terms you need to determine the result.

Comment: We haven't studied Taylor series for $cosh$ so i can't use them, but i am open minded and interested in any kind of solution

Comment: Then, what do you know about $\cosh$? [Seems like you know the Taylor series of $\cos$?]

Comment: I know Taylor series of $cos$, but now it comes to mind that $cosh$ can be represented as series of $e$

Comment: Is $\cosh$ defined via $\cosh x = \frac{1}{2}(e^x + e^{-x})$? Then you get the series representation easily.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Without Taylor series, you may first study the limit (using l'Hôpital's rule):
 $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\cosh(x)-\cos(x)}{x^2} $$